# Only display XML object if tag certain attribute in php codeigniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Videos>
    <video>
        <Title>Video Title</Title>
        <SubHeading>SubTitle</SubHeading>
        <url>UIIArHNaKtE</url>
        <image>image.png</image>
        <category>3</category>
        <latest>0</latest>
    </video>
    <video>
        <Title>Video Title</Title>
        <SubHeading>SubTitle</SubHeading>
        <url>UIIArHNaKtE</url>
        <image>image.png</image>
        <category>3</category>
        <latest>0</latest>
    </video>
    <video>
        <Title>Video Title</Title>
        <SubHeading>SubTitle</SubHeading>
        <url>UIIArHNaKtE</url>
        <image>image.png</image>
        <category>3</category>
        <latest>0</latest>
    </video>
</Videos>
```

With a model file:

```
<?php
class xmlmodel extends CI_Model{

    public function catalog(){

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $path = '../application/libraries/VideoData.xml';
    $doc->load($path);//xml file loading here

    $data = $doc->getElementsByTagName('video');

    return $data;
}
}
```

The Controller:

```
<?php

class SixD extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($sixD = 'latestadditions') {

        if (!file_exists('../application/views/page/' . $sixD . '.php')) {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }
        $this->load->model('xmlmodel');
        $data['category_catalog_entity'] = $this->xmlmodel->catalog();

        $this->lang->load('common/menu.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/headings.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/links.php');
        $this->lang->load('common/footer.php');
        $this->lang->load('page/' . $sixD . '.php');        

        $this->load->view('templates/common/header');
        $this->load->view('page/' . $sixD, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/common/footer');
    }
}
```

And view:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="pageheading">
        <?php echo lang('heading_pageheading'); ?>
    </h1>
    <hr class="heading" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9">
                <?php foreach($category_catalog_entity as $result){ ?>              
                    <div class="row videopane software">
                        <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-push-5">
                            <h3 class="pageheading"><?php echo anchor('http://youtu.be/' . $result->getElementsByTagName('url')->item(0)->nodeValue, $result->getElementsByTagName('Title')->item(0)->nodeValue . '<br /><small>' . $result->getElementsByTagName( "SubHeading" )->item(0)->nodeValue . '</small>', array('class' => 'fancybox-media'));?></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-pull-7 text-center">
                        <?php echo anchor('http://youtu.be/' . $result->getElementsByTagName('url')->item(0)->nodeValue . '?autoplay=1', img("Thumbnails/" . $result->getElementsByTagName('image')->item(0)->nodeValue,  $result->getElementsByTagName('Title')->item(0)->nodeValue,  $result->getElementsByTagName('Title')->item(0)->nodeValue, "img-responsive img-thumbnail"), array('class' => 'fancybox-media')); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php }
                } ?>
                </div>              
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 software">
                    <?php $this->load->view('modules/menu'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This all works however I wish to define what video displays on which page so I have 2 tags:

```
<category>3</category>
<latest>1</latest>
```

and what I want to do is have all videos that have a category of 3 to display on that one page and ignore any other category number. The latest tag is used for new videos so this will either be 1 for active or 0 for do not display.

I should point out each page has a seperate view page but basically uses the same format. There is no database hence I am using XML to control this if anyone can give me some pointers would be very useful.

Comment: an idea would be to use an additional parameter for your catalog()-method and only return the videos of the wanted page. the active or not thingy you also could implement there

Comment: Could you give me an example I should point out the controller and model pages are used for all the views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved this ended up dropping the model file and putting attributes on the xml file:

```
<Videos>
    <video type="Module">
        <Title>TITLE</Title>
        <SubHeading>SUBHEADING</SubHeading>
        <url>YOUTUBECODE</url>
        <image>IMAGE.png</image>
        <description>DESCRIPTIOM</description>
        <link><![CDATA[<a href="/URL"><i class='fa-li fa fa-angle-double-right'></i>LINK</a>]]></link>
        <link2><![CDATA[<a href="/URL"><i class='fa-li fa fa-angle-double-right'></i>LINK</a>]]></link2>
    </video>
    <video type="Module" id="1">
        <Title>TITLE</Title>
        <SubHeading>SUBHEADING</SubHeading>
        <url>YOUTUBECODE</url>
        <image>IMAGE.png</image>
        <description>DESCRIPTIOM</description>
        <link><![CDATA[<a href="/URL"><i class='fa-li fa fa-angle-double-right'></i>LINK</a>]]></link>
        <link2><![CDATA[<a href="/URL"><i class='fa-li fa fa-angle-double-right'></i>LINK</a>]]></link2>
    </video>
    <video type="Common" id="1">
        <Title>TITLE</Title>
        <SubHeading>SUBHEADING</SubHeading>
        <url>YOUTUBECODE</url>
        <image>IMAGE.png</image>
        <description>DESCRIPTIOM</description>
        <link><![CDATA[<a href="/URL"><i class='fa-li fa fa-angle-double-right'></i>LINK</a>]]></link>
        <link2><![CDATA[<a href="/URL"><i class='fa-li fa fa-angle-double-right'></i>LINK</a>]]></link2>
    </video>
</Videos>
```

This allowed me to display individual 'videos' on the pages I wanted. Using:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9">
                    <?php if(file_exists('../application/libraries/VideoData.xml')) {
                        $xml = simplexml_load_file('../application/libraries/VideoData.xml');
                        $count = 0;
                        $counts = 0;
                        foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
                            $role = $child->attributes(); { 
                                if($role["1"])
                                    echo('<div class="media thumbnail software"><div class="' . (++$counts%2 ? "col-sm-5 text-center" : "col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7 text-center") . '">' . anchor('http://youtu.be/' . $child->url . '?autoplay=1', img("Thumbnails/" . $child->image,  $child->Title,  $child->Title, "media-object img-responsive img-thumbnail"), array('class' => 'fancybox-media')) . '</div><div class="media-body ' . (++$count%2 ? "col-sm-7" : "col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5") . '"><h3 class="media-heading pageheading">'.anchor('http://youtu.be/' . $child->url . '?autoplay=1', $child->Title . '<br /><small>' . $child->SubHeading . '</small>', array('class' => 'fancybox-media')) . '</h3><hr class="heading"><p>'. $child->description .'</p><ul class="fa-ul"><li>' . $child->link .'</li></ul></div></div>');
                            }
                        }
                    } ?>
                </div>
```

Or:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9">
                    <?php if(file_exists('../application/libraries/VideoData.xml')) {
                        $xml = simplexml_load_file('../application/libraries/VideoData.xml');
                        $count = 0;
                        $counts = 0;
                        foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
                            $role = $child->attributes(); { 
                                if($role == "Module")
                                    echo('<div class="media thumbnail software"><div class="' . (++$counts%2 ? "col-sm-5 text-center" : "col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7 text-center") . '">' . anchor('http://youtu.be/' . $child->url . '?autoplay=1', img("Thumbnails/" . $child->image,  $child->Title,  $child->Title, "media-object img-responsive img-thumbnail"), array('class' => 'fancybox-media')) . '</div><div class="media-body ' . (++$count%2 ? "col-sm-7" : "col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5") . '"><h3 class="media-heading pageheading">'.anchor('http://youtu.be/' . $child->url . '?autoplay=1', $child->Title . '<br /><small>' . $child->SubHeading . '</small>', array('class' => 'fancybox-media')) . '</h3><hr class="heading"><p>'. $child->description .'</p><ul class="fa-ul"><li>' . $child->link2 .'</li></ul></div></div>');
                            }
                        }
                    } ?>
                </div>
```

Depending what i wanted to display. Thanks for KURN's help as it made me look at different ways of acheiving this and ended up using:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php#113164

to assist me. Hope this helps anyone else :)

Answer (score 0):

i do not know how you handle the whole case with the views/models. but with the actual architecture you wont get the wished result.

i made now a quick&dirty version how i would implement this.

```
public function catalog($category_id = 1)
{
    $data = array();

    //$path = '../application/libraries/VideoData.xml';
    $path = '1.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    foreach ($array['video'] as $video)
    {
        if ($video['category'] == $category_id)
        {
            $data[] = $video;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

of course you could leave your original calatog method and use a new method to only get the wanted videos.

in this way you can call in your controller by an url-parameter the category and only return the filtered result to your view

*edit: as i said this is only quick&dirty... if you want keep your domdocument way :) its just for the idea

Comment: Sorry not getting this to work at all I am probably getting the view side wrong

Comment: as i said, its just to give you an idea how to handle it. you can not 1:1 copy this for your view because i return an array instead of the xml object. i just wanted give you the idea, that you have to make the "filtering" in your model. so i would give you the advice to keep your catalog method as an overview of all videos. if you want to display only specialy categories you should do another method in your model which do the filtering and return only the xml object which is needed. and dont need to be sorry :)

Comment: Ok  I think I have got myself well confused maybe i should have said I am very much a copy and paster lol. More of a designer and just dable in php when I try and save myself time in future. So how would I use your method to then display the different attributes in the view?